# Ce « baroudeur grand sportif » : emboîtement, sens équivalent à la coordination etc. ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, adjectifs, argot, ellipse

L'héroïque (M.) Jean-Jacques Savin ([identifié](http://www.chemin-de-memoire-parachutistes.org/t11657-exploit-de-jean-jacques-savin-parce-quil-est-para-dont-le-9-mais-aussi-le-1er-rcp-et-le-1er-rpima-et-mon-ami) [*9<sup>e</sup> RCP*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/9e_r%C3%A9giment_de_chasseurs_parachutistes), [*1<sup>er</sup> RCP*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1er_r%C3%A9giment_de_chasseurs_parachutistes), [*1<sup>er</sup> RPIMa*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1er_r%C3%A9giment_de_parachutistes_d%27infanterie_de_marine)) traverse [actuellement](http://weedex.lu/barrel/) l'[*Atlantique* en tonneau](http://www.atlantique-tonneau.com/#accueil). On peut [lire](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/insolite/201901/13/01-5210866-laventurier-qui-traverse-latlantique-dans-un-tonneau-a-parcouru-400-km.php) que :

> Ce *baroudeur grand sportif* s'est lancé à la mer le 26 décembre de
>   l'île d'El Hierro pour traverser l'Atlantique par la seule force des
>   courants [...] (La Presse)

Un [*baroudeur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baroudeur) (f. *baroudeuse*), de l'argot des casernes, est « celui qui aime le [baroud](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baroud) » (TLFi), soit la « guerre, le combat, ou qui a beaucoup combattu » ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/baroudeur_baroudeuse/8088)), ou familièrement la personne « dynamique, qui aime les risques ; aventurier » ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/baroudeur_baroudeuse/8088)). Tous les sens peuvent sans doute s'appliquer à M. Savin. Le [*sportif*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sportif) peut être nom ou adjectif ; un [*combat*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/combat) peut être au figuré. Dans [certains cas](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4661) un nom peut servir d'épithète. Des épithètes peuvent être jointes sans être coordonnées ; parfois il y a emboîtement (une *aimable vieille dame* ; *aimable* sert d'épithète à l'ensemble *vieille dame*) ou un élément peut être subordonné à un autre (des yeux bleu clair ; *clair* est considéré subordonné à *bleu*) (LBU14, § 331).

---

- Peut-on analyser *baroudeur grand sportif* : nature des mots
  (adjectif, nom), ensembles, éléments subordonnés ; est-ce
  l'équivalent de *baroudeur et grand sportif* : s'agit-il d'une simple
  omission de la coordination ?
- Incidemment, en ce qui a trait au sens de *baroudeur*, peut-on
  l'employer pour une personne qui n'est pas militaire et qui n'aime
  pas le risque mais qui aimerait le *combat* (au figuré) ?
- Subsidiairement peut-on confirmer le féminin formé en *-euse* ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Il est assez possible, il me semble, qu'il ait été l'intention de l'auteur de voir un nom composé dans son terme, comme dans « cet athlète casse-cou », « ce chanteur acteur », cet « enseignant mythomane », qui sont des constructions acceptées.
2. On trouve une attestation irréfutable de l'existence du terme « baroudeuse », puisqu'il est porté comme entrée dans le dictionnaire [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/baroudeur_baroudeuse/8088).
3. On trouve de même une confirmation de l'existence du sens figuré à cette même entrée du Larousse.